# remove extra parentheses from the list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

I got list from database:

```
print(rows)
print(type(rows))
[('simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{4} + \\frac{1}{2} $$',), ('simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$',)]
<class 'list'>
```

I need remove extra parentheses, quotes and commas from the list. As results I should get:

```
print(rows[0])
print(rows[1])

simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{4} + \\frac{1}{2} $$
simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$
```

How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
print(rows[0][0])
print(rows[1][0])
```

to get what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can just transform your rows like this:

```
rows = [row[0] for row in rows]
print(rows)
['simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{4} + \\frac{1}{2} $$', 'simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$']
```

and then you simple access just like you do:

```
print(rows[0])
print(rows[1])

simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{4} + \\frac{1}{2} $$
simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$
```

**Explaination:**

the problem you faced (which isn't really a problem :) ) that you got tuples inside each list, that each of them contains 1 element, it isn't a bigger string or something like that , so I changes your list to strip out the unwanted tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
print(*rows[0]) # print the unpack tuple located at rows[0]
print(*rows[1]) # print the unpack tuple located at rows[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the loop because there can be more than 2 in the future.
in this case, there are 5 values from the database...

#### Code:

```
rows = [('simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{4} + \\frac{1}{2} $$',),
 ('simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$',),
 ('simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$',),
 ('simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$',),
 ('simplify expression: $$ \\frac{1}{3} + \\frac{2}{3} $$',)]

total_count = len(rows)

for i in range(0, total_count):
    print(rows[i][0])
```

#### OutPut:

```
simplify expression: $$ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} $$
simplify expression: $$ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} $$
simplify expression: $$ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} $$
simplify expression: $$ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} $$
simplify expression: $$ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} $$
```